# Calculate the total size of SD card from CSD register in SPI mode

Tags: sd-card, spi

I'm trying to calculate the total size of the SD Card from the CSD register, from the datasheet the bits[69:48] represent the device size.

But this actually represents a different number of the total size, even after multiplay this number with the block size it is still in megabytes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/embedded/dey/3.0/cc6plus/yocto_r_uboot-mmc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.